# How 'AND' and 'OR' can be combined in advanced twitter search operators?

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

I want to find tweets including one of these three possibility in search results:

- "**AAAA**" and "**BBBB**"

or

- "**AAAA**" and "**CCCC**"

or

- "**AAAA**" and "**BBBB**" and "**CCCC**"

I mean that `AAAA` should be in tweets results and one (or both) of `BBBB` and `CCCC` should be included too.

How AAAA, BBBB and CCCC should be arranged using one `AND` operator and one `OR` operator to get the described result?

Answer (score 0):

(AAAA BBBB) OR (AAAA CCCC) OR (AAAA BBBB CCCC) 
Should work but more search operators can be seen here: 
search.twitter.com --> Advanced search or search operators.

[image]